# Can't figure out why abstract method isn't overriding

Tags: java

My programming assignment tasked me with writing an increase/decreasePay abstract method that must be put in my abstract employee class. I can't seem to get the the method correct in HourlyWorker so that it will take increase or decrease the pay by a "percentage". My math is sound (monthly pay - or + (monthly pay * the percentage), but my output in my test class is coming out the same after increasing/decreasing pay. Any help?

Employee class:

```
abstract public class Employee
{

private String lastName;
private String firstName;
private String ID;


public abstract void increasePay(double percentage);
public abstract void decreasePay(double percentage);
public abstract double getMonthlyPay();

public Employee(String last, String first, String ID)
   {
   lastName = last;
   firstName = first;
   this.ID = ID;
   } 

public void setLast(String last)
   {
      lastName = last;
   }
   
public void setFirst(String first)
   {
      firstName = first;
   }
   
public void setIdNumber(String ID)
   {
      this.ID = ID;
   }

      
public String getLastName()
{
   return lastName;
}

public String getFirstName()
{
   return firstName;
}

public String getName()
{
   return firstName + lastName;
}

public String getIdNumber()
{
   return ID;
}
```

}

---

HourlyWorkerClass

```
public class HourlyWorker extends Employee
{
private int hours;
private double hourlyRate;
private double monthlyPay;

public HourlyWorker(String last, String first, String ID, double rate)
{
   super(last, first, ID);
   hourlyRate = rate;
}

public void setHours(int hours)
{
   this.hours = hours;
}

public int getHours()
{
   return hours;
}

public void setHourlyRate(double rate)
{
   if ( hours > 160 )
       this.hourlyRate = hourlyRate * 1.5;
    else 
       this.hourlyRate = rate;
}

public double getHourlyRate()
{
   return hourlyRate;
}


public void setMonthlyPay(double monthlyPay)
{
   monthlyPay = hourlyRate * hours;
}

public double getMonthlyPay()
{
   return hourlyRate * hours;
}

public void increasePay(double percentage)
{
   monthlyPay = monthlyPay* percentage;
}

public void decreasePay(double percentage)
{
   monthlyPay = monthlyPay* percentage;
}

public String toString() 
   {
        String result = "Name: " + getFirstName() + " " + getLastName() + "\nID: "
                         + getIdNumber() + " \nHourly Rate: " + hourlyRate;
                        return result;
   }

}
```

---

Testing class (currently testing increase

```
public class TestEmployee2
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   Employee [] staff = new Employee[3];
      Supervisor sup = new Supervisor("Boss", "Jim", "JB7865", 54000);
      HourlyWorker hw1 = new HourlyWorker("Bee", "Busy", "BB1265", 11.95);

      hw1.setHours(200);
            
      staff[0] = sup;
      staff[1] = hw1;        
      
   System.out.println(staff[0].getMonthlyPay());
   staff[0].increasePay(5);
   System.out.println(staff[0].getMonthlyPay());

   System.out.println(staff[1].getMonthlyPay());
   staff[1].increasePay(10);
   System.out.println(staff[1].getMonthlyPay());
   
}
}
```

---

Supervisor class:

```
public class Supervisor extends Employee
{
private double annualSalary;
private double monthlyPay;

public Supervisor(String last, String first, String ID, double salary)
{
   super(last, first, ID);
   annualSalary = salary;
}

public void setAnnualSalary(double salary)
{
   annualSalary = salary;
}

public double getAnnualSalary()
{
   return annualSalary;
}

public double getMonthlyPay()
{
   return ((annualSalary + (annualSalary * .02)) / 12);
}

public void increasePay(double percentage)
{
   monthlyPay = monthlyPay* percentage;
}

public void decreasePay(double percentage)
{
   monthlyPay = monthlyPay* percentage;
}

public String toString() 
   {
        String result = "Name: " + getFirstName() + " " + getLastName() + "\nID: "
                         + getIdNumber() + "\nAnnual Salary: " + annualSalary;
         return result;
   }
}
```

Output is:

4590.0
4590.0
2390.0
2390.0

Doesn't appear to be modifying getMonthlyPay()

Should be:

4590.00
4819.50
2390.00
2629.00

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @TomerShetah no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `increasePay`, you are increasing `monthlyPay`:

```
public void increasePay(double percentage)
{
   monthlyPay = monthlyPay* percentage;
}
```

But when you `getMonthlyPay`, you calculate the pay using two other variables - `hourlyRate` and `hours`:

```
public double getMonthlyPay()
{
   return hourlyRate * hours;
}
```

So changing `monthlyPay` doesn't affect what `getMonthlyPay` returns. I suspect a similar thing happens in `Supervisor`.

`increasePay` should instead increase `hourlyRate`:

```
public void increasePay(double percentage)
{
   hourlyRate *= 1 + percentage / 100;
}
```

Also, I don't think you need a `monthlyPay` field (or `setMonthlyPay`, for that matter) in `HourlyEmployee` at all. The monthly rate can always be calculated by `hours` and `hourlyRate`.

---

For `Supervisor`, do the same thing, and change `annualSalary` rather than `monthlyPay`:

```
public double getMonthlyPay()
{
   return ((annualSalary + (annualSalary * .02)) / 12);
}

public void increasePay(double percentage)
{
   annualSalary *= 1 + percentage / 100;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Is there any way to do it with the monthly pay. I'm supposed to increase decrease the monthly pay by x percentage. Your method works for Hourly Employee by increasing hourly rate by x percentage, but in Supervisor(I've edited the post to include the supervisor class), there is only an annual salary (which is the salary + a bonus). When I do something like 

        public void decreasePay(double percentage)
        {
        annualSalary = annualSalary - (annualSalary / percentage)
        }

The number is slightly off because it's doing the math beforehand

Comment: Also, for the 5% increase, I was given the test code lines that I need to satisfy of: 

staff[0].increasePay(5);

with 5 being the percent I need to increase the monthly payment by. This is what I'm trying to tailor my code towards

Comment: @ChocolateGoosePoosey Why is monthly pay calculated as `((annualSalary + (annualSalary * .02)) / 12)`? Shouldn't it be `annualSalary / 12`?

Comment: There is a 2 percent bonus that is applied to the salary. Then I am dividing by 12 to find the monthly pay

Comment: @ChocolateGoosePoosey It is possible to do with monthly pay, but then you should remove the `hourlyRate` field, and calculate the hourly rate using the monthly rate and `hours` instead. There should be a single source of truth.

Comment: I just realized that I should be calculating that bonus before the getMonthlyPay method. Ah

Comment: unfortunately, these variables are required. The hourly worker class appears to be working, though

Comment: where do I add the 2% bonus? Nothing happens when I put it in either the setter or getter methods?

Comment: @ChocolateGoosePoosey See the edit. Your code seems to be correct. Your expected output seems to be wrong. 4590.00 increased by 5% is 4819.5, not what you expected.

Comment: I see that I was expecting a 10% increase there instead of 5%. You're correct with 4819.5. However, my code still isnt calculating correctly, even with something like: 

public void increasePay(double percentage)
{
   annualSalary += annualSalary * percentage;
}

Comment: @ChocolateGoosePoosey As I said in my answer, that won't work. You should change `annualSalary`,not `monthlyPay`.

Comment: Ah, just saw the edit. That Works. Thanks. Stay gold